# Haskell design encompassing several monads

Tags: design-patterns, haskell

Trying to learn Haskell I'm implementing a [Quarto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quarto_%28board_game%29) game in Haskell. I have already implemented the game in Python as an exercise in a course I took last year where the idea was to implement the game together with three different "AI" players, a random player, a novice player and a minimax player. The piece logic and board logic is quite straight forward to implement, but I have come to the point where I need to implement the players and I'm wondering how to best design the players so that the game logic doesn't need to know anything about the specific players, but still allowing them to use different monads.

The problem is that each player needs different monads, the random player needs to work in either a State monad or a RandomState monad. The novice player will probably also need some form of state and the minimax player could use either state or be pure(this would make it much slower and a bit trickier to implement, but it can be done) in addition i would like a "human" player which will need to work in the IO monad to get input from a human. One easy solution is to just put everything in the IO monad, but I feel that it is somewhat making the individual design harder and forcing the design of each player to have to deal with more than they should have to.

My initial thought would be something like:

```
class QuartoPlayer where
    place :: (Monad m) => QuartoPiece -> QuartoBoard -> m (Int, Int)
    nextPiece :: (Monad m) => QuartoBoard -> [QuartoPiece] -> m QuartoPiece
```

I don't know if this will work as I have not tried it, but I would like some input if I'm headed in the right direction and if the design makes sense in Haskell.

Comment: use monad transformers `Control.Monad.Trans.*` to combine several Monads

Comment: Yes, monad transformers is the answer. With monad transformers, you can build a single, combined monad out of several monads, and the combination has all the capabilities of the individual monads.

Comment: Would that mean that all "players" would have to share the same monads?

Comment: @Nordmoen: if they must share them, then "yes". And in many cases for simplification "yes" too. Read for example this: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Monad_transformers

Comment: @user2181660 Is it possible to separate them from each other explicitly? I would really like to have them separated as each player will only need "their own monads", e.g. the human player will only need the IO monad, but the minimax player will not need IO, but could use State

Comment: `lift :: Monad m => m a -> t m a` You  could use nested `lift` to up. Like `lift $ lift f`.

Comment: Use FreeMonad which lets you share the same Monadic blocks in different monads.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two parts to what is going on here. First is how to combine the several different types of monad to run at the same time — and as has been pointed out this can be done with monad transformers — and the second is allowing each of your player types access only to the monads they need. The answer to this latter problem is type classes.

So firstly, lets examine monad transformers. A monad transformer is like a monad with an additional 'internal' monad. If this internal monad is the Identity monad (which basically does nothing) then the behaviour is just like the regular monad. For this reason monad are usually implemented as transformers and wrapped in Identity to export a normal monad. Transformer versions of monads usually append T to the end of the type, so the state monad transformer is called StateT. The only difference in the types is in the addition of the inner monad, `State s a` vs `Monad m => StateT s m a`. So for an example, an IO monad with an attached list of integers as state could have type `StateT [Int] IO`.

Two more points are needed to properly use the transformers. First is that to effect the inner monad, you use the `lift` function (which any existing monad transformer will have defined). Each call of lift moves you one down the stack of transformers. `liftIO` is a special shortcut for when the IO monad is at the bottom of the stack. (And it can't be anywhere else as there is no IO transformer as you would expect.) So we could make a function that pops the head of our int list from the state part and prints it using the IO part:

```
popAndPrint :: StateT [Int] IO Int
popAndPrint = do
    (x:xs) <- get
    liftIO $ print x
    put xs
    return x
```

The second point is that you need transformer versions of the running functions, one for each monad transformer in the stack. So in this case to demonstrate the effect in GHCi we need

```
> runStateT popAndPrint  [1,2,3]
1
(1,[2,3])
```

If we wrapped this in an Error monad, we'd need to call `runErrorT $ runStateT popAndPrint [1,2,3]` and so on.

That is a quick fire intro to monad transformers, there is plenty more available online.

However, for you this is only half of the story, as ideally you want a separation between which monads your different player types can use. The transformer approach seems to give you everything and you don't really want to give all the players access to IO just because one needs it. So how to proceed?

Each different type of player needs access to a different part of the transformer stack. So make a type class for each player that exposes only what that player needs. Each one could go in a different file. For example:

```
-- IOPlayer.hs
class IOPlayerMonad a where
    getMove :: IO Move

doSomethingWithIOPLayer :: IOPlayerMonad m => m ()
doSomethingWithIOPLayer = ...

-- StatePlayer.hs
class StatePlayerMonad s a where
    get :: Monad m => StateT s m s
    put :: Monad m => s -> StateT s m ()

doSomethingWithStatePlayer :: StatePlayerMonad s m => m ()
doSomethingWithStatePlayer = ...

-- main.hs
instance IOPlayerMonad (StateT [Int] IO) where
   getMove = liftIO getMoveIO

instance StatePlayerMonad s (StateT [Int] IO) where
   get' = get
   put' = put
```

This gives you control over what part of the app can access what from the overall state, and this control all happens in one file. Each individual part gets to define its interface and logic quite apart from specific implementation of the main state.

PS, you may need these at the top:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

import Control.Monad.Trans.State
import Control.Monad.IO.Class
import Control.Monad
```

-

## UPDATE

There has been some confusion about whether you can do it this way and still have a common interface to all players. I maintain that you can. Haskell is not object oriented and so we need to do a little bit of the dispatch plumbing ourselves, but the results are just as powerful and you get better control of the details and can still achieve full encapsulation. To better show this I have included a fully working toy example.

Here we see that the `Play` class provides a single interface to a number of different player types, each with their logic in their own file and only seeing a specific interface onto the transformer stack. This interface is controlled in the Play module, and the game logic need use only this interface.

Adding a new player involves making a new file for them, designing the interface they require, adding this to the AppMonad, and wiring it up with a new tag in the Player type.

Note that all players get access to the board via the AppMonadClass class, which could be expanded to include any required common interface elements.

```
-- Common.hs --
data Board = Board
data Move = Move

data Player = IOPlayer | StackPlayer Int

class Monad m => AppMonadClass m where
    board :: m Board

class Monad m => Play m where
    play :: Player -> m Move

-- IOPlayer.hs --
import Common

class AppMonadClass m => IOPLayerMonad m where
    doIO :: IO a -> m a

play1 :: IOPLayerMonad m => m Move
play1 = do
    b <- board
    move <- doIO (return Move)
    return move


-- StackPlayer.hs --
import Common

class AppMonadClass m => StackPlayerMonad s m | m -> s where
    pop  :: Monad m => m s
    peak :: Monad m => m s
    push :: Monad m => s -> m ()

play2 :: (StackPlayerMonad Int m) => Int -> m Move
play2 x = do
    b <- board
    x <- peak
    push x
    return Move


-- Play.hs --
import Common
import IOPLayer
import StackPlayer

type AppMonad = StateT [Int] (StateT Board IO)

instance AppMonadClass AppMonad where
    board = return Board

instance StackPlayerMonad Int AppMonad where
    pop  = do (x:xs) <- get; put xs; return x;
    peak = do (x:xs) <- get; return x;
    push x = do (xs) <- get; put (x:xs);

instance IOPLayerMonad AppMonad where
    doIO = liftIO

instance Play AppMonad where
    play IOPlayer = play1
    play (StackPlayer x) = play2 x


-- GameLogic.hs
import Play

updateBoard :: Move -> Board -> Board
updateBoard _ = id

players :: [Player]
players = [IOPlayer, StackPlayer 4]

oneTurn :: Player -> AppMonad ()
oneTurn p = do
    move <- play p
    oldBoard <- lift get
    newBoard <- return $ updateBoard move oldBoard
    lift $ put newBoard
    liftIO $ print newBoard

oneRound :: AppMonad [()]
oneRound = forM players $ (\player -> oneTurn player)

loop :: AppMonad ()
loop = forever oneRound

main = evalStateT (evalStateT loop [1,2,3]) Board
```

Comment: First of all, a very good introduction to monad transformers, I tried reading a bit about it after the previous comments and your summary perfectly sums what I read, but much more concise. One question I have though, is, can I with your system handle all players interchangeably? From the game logic point of view I would like all implemented players to appear similar. Something a long the lines of defining an interface in Java having some special code initialize the needed players and having the game logic only work on the interface.

Comment: You should be able to make a data instance like data `Player = IOPayer | StatePlayer | etc` and then have a method in the main module that switches on that type, and then gets the correct effect from the other player files. It can do this because the main module knows about the whole stack and so will type check. So this main module can provide a unified interface to a player, while each different player module knows only what it needs via its type class interface. (Bear in mind I'm calling it main but it doesn't have to be *the* main)

Comment: Hm, that would still mean that the game logic(your main) would have to know about the specific players. Would it not be possible to build something which would make the game logic completely oblivious to the specific type. Using your suggestion would it be possible to build another layer on top of StatePlayer and IOPlayer which could make the logic not have to know if its a StatePlayer or an IOPlayer?

Comment: @Nordmoen different monads mean different interactions with the stateful world. Mixing them is like mixing Java InputStream with PrintWriter - how can they possibly be used by the same code? It seems to me when you say "different monads", you mean something other than what Vic Smith means

Comment: @SassaNF It seems we do, I think the mismatch is at my end because I keep thinking that an Interface in Java comprises the same functionality, but it doesn't because it is not pure which means you can easily combine several things that should(must?) be kept separate in Haskell(e.g. IO and State can be combined in Java, not in Haskell).

Comment: I have included a full example to try and help resolve your concerns. All of the monad effects are encapsulated, and a single class provides an interface onto all players.